# How to hide FAB from subfragment?

Tags: android, material-design

Well, i have an Activity(with ViewPager and FAB)

In ViewPager there is a NotesFragment(fragment contains only RecyclerView)

And I have a Fragment calls AddNoteFragment which do the job of Adding and Showing existing Note:
1) From Activity fab opens AddNoteFragment to add note, which is logical,
2) And from RecyclerView, clicking item opens AddNoteFragment with details of clicked item

Question: how to hide FAB on Activity, when i'm opening AddNoteFragment to show exciting note correctly? The only way I know is a using interface and transfering it up, but this will look like RecyclerViewAdapter -> NotesFragment -> ViewPagerAdapter -> Activity, it looks weird..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I think using interface it's a good way to do it, you might want to take a look at EventBus (https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus), it works similary as BroadcastReceiver, all you have to do is to wait for the event on your Activity, and hide/show it whenever you want. Below is the code you have to put on your activity:

```
@Override
 public void onStart() {
     super.onStart();
     EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
 }

 @Override
 public void onStop() {
     super.onStop();
     EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
 }

@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)  
public void onMessageEvent(Boolean show) {if (show){
  fab.show()
}else{
  fab.hide()
}};
```

then, whenever you want, you just have to call this

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(/* true or false*/);
```

Comment: 1) Why do we need to use interfaces for such situations? What should I read for this? I've learned it from comments on this site.
2) One man said me once that EventBus is a memoryleak because it creates global objects. Is that true? But I have to admit, it looks very comfortable...

Comment: 1) Because interfaces are made exactly to handle situations like this. Whenever you want to have a communication between fragments and activities, interfaces will solve you problem. You can check a good example on this link http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-communicate-between-fragments-and-activities/

Comment: 2) Probably if you're not using correctly, just make sure to unregister whenever yo do not using the listeners anymore and I think you'll be fine. Also, it's a very well know lib that have more than 20k stars, so it's a good indicator that it's a solid lib